# Node JS App | server.js changes not reflecting on Azure App Service after deploying and restart of app service

Tags: reactjs, node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have SPA in React JS and Node JS hosted on Azure App service. I use `gulp build` command to build a solution and use FileZilla to upload files in `dist` folder. Manually restart the app service to reflect the changes in the server.js file.

This was working for me earlier. Since the last 3 days after restarting the app service also changes in server.js have not been reflected although the changes in client.js and other files are reflecting.

How to get it worked?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Are you deploying React.js and Node.js in a single web app?

Comment: @Dhanshri Tekale please share the code of react, nodejs and please the error also

Answer (score 0):

The simple below React code application fetches data from a server using Axios and displays it on the front end, with the server as Node and the client as React.

The server listens on port 3001 and has a single route `'/'`, responding with 'Hello World!'. It also utilizes the `cors` middleware to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), allowing the React app to fetch data from this server.

In the client, there is an async function called `fetchDataFromServer`, which uses Axios to make a GET request to `http://localhost:3001/`.

**server.js:**

```js
// server.js

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors'); // Import the cors package
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Enable CORS for all routes
app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

**react code :**

```js
// client.js

import axios from 'axios';

const fetchDataFromServer = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/'); // Replace '/api/data' with your actual API endpoint
    console.log('Data from server:', response.data);
    return response.data; // Return the fetched data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    throw error; // Throw error to handle it in the calling component
  }
};

export { fetchDataFromServer };
```

```js
// App.js

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { fetchDataFromServer } from './client'; // Importing the fetchDataFromServer function

const App = () => {
  const [serverData, setServerData] = useState(null); // State to store fetched server data

  useEffect(() => {
    // Call fetchDataFromServer when the component mounts
    fetchDataFromServer()
      .then(data => {
        // Set the fetched data to the state
        setServerData(data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Handle errors
        console.error('Error in App component:', error);
      });
  }, []); // Run this effect only once when the component mounts

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Render server data if available */}
      {serverData ? (
        <div>
          <h1>Hello, React App!</h1>
          <p>Server Data: {serverData}</p> {/* Render server data here */}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>Loading...</p> // Render loading message while data is being fetched
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Local:**
[image]

**Azure:**
[image]